# Changing navigationBar's title based on position in scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to change the navigationBar's title based on a scrollView's x position. Here's the code I have. I don't know why it's not working or if it's possible though:

```
if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "First"
        }
        else if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Second"
        }
        else if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width*2) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Third"
        }
```

Any ideas as to what's going wrong? I put this in the `viewDidLoad` of the ViewController the scrollView is in. It's only setting the navigationBar's title as "First". Is it because I put in viewDidLoad? Do I have to put it into a new method that updates?

I also tried putting the following code in, updating when the scrollView ended dragging. This does not change anything though:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "First"
        }
        else if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Second"
        }
        else if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width*2) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Third"
        }
    }
```

`self.scrollView.contentOffset.x` keeps logging null within `scrollViewDidEndDragging`. Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code to [scrollViewDidScroll:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:) method and don't forget to set self as a delegate for scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code inside `scrollViewDidScroll()` delegate method, and if you calculations are alright, it will work. Good Luck!